# Is Forms Authentication totally necessary?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, session, authentication, webforms

I'm writing an internal web application right now (with ASP.Net Web Forms), and it presents an odd problem. I have to be able to impersonate the currently logged in windows user, and execute a command based on their Windows Authentication to log in.. AND ... if they don't have Windows Authentication set up in the application I have to use to log them in, I have to be able to accept a user name and password. I also have to write the application in .Net 4.0, and secure it as much as possible. I got this to work by NOT utilizing Windows Authentication or Forms Authentication in the web.config, and instead setting session variables to guard against user accessing pages in the web app other that the log in. I did this by creating an oddly name session variable with a value based on their user name (windows auth or not), and then a secret session variable. The secret variable is in the web.config as a 256bit encrypted string, in which I decrypt, and set as the session secret. In order for the page to load, the first session variable can't be blank, and the second variable has to equal the decrypted key value... if the variables don't pass inspection, it redirects them to the login page. I set this up on every page, generic handler, and webservice method in the web app. I make the session timeout after a few minutes of no activity, and on log out, I set all session variables to nothing, and expire  all cookies. (I also disable all cache).

My question is... Does this offer comparable security to that of Forms authentication? I have always used Forms authentication, but can't use it here. If I did, the users would have to reconfigure settings in IIS and in he web.config to toggle login procedures (From my knowledge, you can't use both Forms authentication, and windows authentication to manage the security of your pages and other web resources). With the method described above, I can accomplish the best of both worlds, but am curious about the security of my methods. Is there anything else I can implement here to assure the utmost security other that using forms authentication? Is it possible to accomplish the same level of security of Forms authentication without using it?

Thank you for any insight in advance!

Comment: wow, after a couple years... I feel dumb asking this question. Of course what I described is crap compared to Forms Authentication #facepalm. I ended up using Forms Auth with Kerberos and a custom membership provider to get the job done.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Does this offer comparable security to that of Forms authentication?

**No**

The first rule when it comes to security is don't reinvent the wheel unless you absolutely have to. Any home baked solution you come up with has the *potential* to be as secure as a provided one like Windows or Forms Authentication. The problem is that home-grown solutions rarely reach that potential. They may test okay, but subtle bugs can remain. You don't want to find out a year later that you were hacked six months ago.  Existing solutions have already been tested and used in millions of applications, whereas yours will be used in one application and tested by a handful of people at most.

A quick search suggests that it is possible to implement both Windows and Forms Authentication in the same application, so I'd pursue it further.

[Mixing Forms and Windows Security in ASP.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972958.aspx)

Comment: Also storing credentials in the session as you suggest in a security hole. Agree with above, although it sounds like all you need is windows auth.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! The only problem is... Mixing both is very querky... Maybe I'll try it again, but it's not as full proof as they make it out to be in that article (which I already read and tried). The issue also lies in the fact I'm using a 3rd part program that I have to use.. to authenticate the user into the site. The program allows for windows auth (which requires impersonation) or UN and PW. Using impersonation with .Net 4.0 framework, and windows auth, and allowing user to get to the login screen without enter their domain creds is also very quirky

Comment: @TheCodeKing .. I'm storing creds as a 256bit encrypted string in the web.config. They would have to decrypt the name of the session (which is hard coded), and decrypt the secret to get in... there may be some hole that can some how get around that... anyway, thanks to everyone for the advice.. and I'll just have to figure out some other way to do this, because mixing auth's with this 3rd part app, .net 4.0 and impersonation doesn't behave consistently enough.

Comment: The issue with session based authentication or authorisation is it's open to session hijacking, session replay, man-in-middle attacks which could allow a hacker to compromise an account. No decryption required. Custom auth is always a bad idea, it wouldn't be as secure as the built-in implementations. Why don't you just use Windows auth or forms auth on it's own? Either one allows you to create a new user.

Comment: @wakurth - you can build your own membership provider that inherits from the existing providers. This will have some of the benefits of rolling your own without as many drawbacks.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn ... I did end up using a custom role provider and membership provider with windows authentication & user name / password. thanks for the response.